# How to create a ratio score from values in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   BIB#            COURSE  FINISH
0     1          COURSE 1  21.235
1     1          COURSE 2  23.345
2     1  STRAIGHT-GLIDING  20.690
3     2          COURSE 1  20.220
4     2          COURSE 2  22.535
5     2  STRAIGHT-GLIDING  19.910
```

Now I want to calculate a ratio score for each BIB#. The ratio score should look like this:

**PERFORMANCE = COURSE 1 + COURSE 2 / STRAIGHT-GLIDING**

The values for this calculation is found in the FINISH column.

I think I can create a function that loops over each row in the DataFrame but I guess there is a better way to do it using Pandas? Thanks!

(If I were to create the function, then I would loop through each BIB# with if tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), then add and divide columns each other:

```
df1 = df.pivot('BIB#','COURSE','FINISH')
df1['PERFORMANCE'] = df1['COURSE 1'].add(df1['COURSE 2']).div(df1['STRAIGHT-GLIDING'])
print (df1)
COURSE  COURSE 1  COURSE 2  STRAIGHT-GLIDING  PERFORMANCE
BIB#                                                     
1         21.235    23.345             20.69     2.154664
2         20.220    22.535             19.91     2.147413
```

If need same format like original add [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = df1.stack().reset_index(name='FINISH')
print (df2)
   BIB#            COURSE     FINISH
0     1          COURSE 1  21.235000
1     1          COURSE 2  23.345000
2     1  STRAIGHT-GLIDING  20.690000
3     1       PERFORMANCE   2.154664
4     2          COURSE 1  20.220000
5     2          COURSE 2  22.535000
6     2  STRAIGHT-GLIDING  19.910000
7     2       PERFORMANCE   2.147413
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to pivot. I have never used that before. One question: will it be easier to make plots and statistics if I stack the dataframe?

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen - The best working with data in pandas is like format `df1`, not in format `df2`, but it depends what need exacly ;)

Comment: Say I want to create a simple catplot in seaborn https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html - what do you think then?

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen - ya, then need `df2`

Comment: cheers :-) You have helped me a lot today! Now I need to learn about pivoting in Pandas

Comment: I need to find the mean of the COURSE 1 AND COURSE 2 instead. My solution: df1['SUMLOYPER'] = df1['COURSE 1'].add(df1['COURSE 2']) / 2
df1['PRESTASJON'] = df1['SUMLOYPER'].div(df1['STRAIGHT-GLIDING'])

Comment: @ChristianMagelssen - Or use `df1['MEAN'] = df1['COURSE 1'].add(df1['COURSE 2']).div(d)` - add and divide 2